# why setState in setTimeout be called twice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, settimeout

I have two state variable that I update them in func function . we know every render in component has own setTimeout . so when I write text fast in input ، I expect that result of number state be 1 once . Its result is 1 but it log twice in console . why?

```
export default function Mycomponent() {
  const [number,setnumber] =useState(0);
  const [string,setstring] =useState('');
  function func(event){
     
    setstring(event.target.value);
    setTimeout(()=>{
      setnumber(number+1);
    },3000);
    // 1_ every render has own setTimeout  so when I write text fast in input  I expect that result of number be 1 once .
    // its result is 1 but it log twice in console. why ??? 
    

      
  }
  console.log(number,string);
  return (
    <>
      <input type='text'onChange={(e)=>{func(e)}} value={string}/>
      
    </>
  )
  
}
```

[image]

Comment: `useState` is bailing after multiple `setState` calls with the same value. It should actually be logging `1 'abcd'` 4 times. If you use a callback in your `setnumber` call you will see this. `setnumber(number => number+1);`

Comment: If you really want number 1 to only show up once in the console you need to remember to cancel the previous timeouts when setting the new one

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour of React is documented.

The whole issue can be seen even without the `setTimeout` where you simply update number.

```
export default function App() {
  const [number, setnumber] = useState(0);
  const [string, setstring] = useState("");
  function func(event) {
    setnumber(1);
  }
  console.log(number, string);
  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={(e) => {
          func(e);
        }}
        value={string}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

Even if you run the above code and start typing : `1 ""` will be logged twice. [Playground](https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-cache-hu4cty?file=/src/App.js:58-410)

This is documented in the [React docs](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#bailing-out-of-a-state-update). React can bail out of renders if the previous and new state values are same, but it might have to rerender the current component. It will definitely bail our for children though and that is why, this not a performance issue.
From the docs:

> Note that React may still need to render that specific component again before bailing out. That shouldn’t be a concern because React won’t unnecessarily go “deeper” into the tree.

To validate the above just create a child component and see how it is not re-rendered twice.

```
export default function App() {
  const [number, setnumber] = useState(0);
  const [string, setstring] = useState("");
  function func(event) {
    setstring(event.target.value);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setnumber(number + 1);
    }, 3000);
    // 1_ every render has own setTimeout  so when I write text fast in input  I expect that result of number be 1 once .
    // its result is 1 but it log twice in console. why ???
  }
  console.log(number, string);
  return (
    <>
      <TestChild />
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={(e) => {
          func(e);
        }}
        value={string}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

[Playground](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-cloud-bvrbuy?file=/src/App.js)